# How might I display HTML text in BlackBerry 4.5?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I display HTML text in BlackBerry 6.0 with a BrowserField. How can I this in Blackberry 4.5?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this answer by the following url.
http://208.74.204.192/t5/Java-Development/how-to-read-text-from-html-data/m-p/1291965#M172853

Which is posted by myself alishaik786.